# GNU Assembler sys_write is not working

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I wrote a simple ASM Programm but sys_write is not giving any output. I guess that I did a mistake with the pointer into %ecx and sys_write can not access the string - but I do not find my mistake so far. Return code after sys_write is stored in %eax and is less 0.
There are a lot of "Hello World"-Examples but I like to understand what I am doing wrong and not the fact that there is other working code :-)
I use Intel-syntax with prefix.
the gdb output looks like this:

```
gdb ./testsasm 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
...
Reading symbols from ./testsasm...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004d6: file t.asm, line 13.
(gdb) n
The program is not being run.
(gdb) run
Starting program: ...src/gnu_asm/testsasm 

Breakpoint 1, main () at t.asm:13
13          mov  %ebx,0x1            # file handle stdout
(gdb) n
14          mov  %eax,0x4            # systemcall sys_write
(gdb) n
15          mov  %ecx,string         # pointer of the string const
(gdb) n
16          mov  %edx,slen           # string lenght
(gdb) n
17          int  0x80             # call write
(gdb) print $ecx
$1 = 1819043144
(gdb) print $edx
$2 = 7
(gdb) print *$ecx
Cannot access memory at address 0x6c6c6548
(gdb)
```

Makefile and source can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23115239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird, nobody uses `.intel_syntax` without `.intel_syntax noprefix` (so you don't need the `%`s on register names, and `$` on immediates).

You should definitely have included that in your question.  (Update: oh, you did, but only buried in the text of a paragraph that looked like it was just stating what was in your gdb output).  I only noticed when I looked at your full-source link since it was weird that you didn't say anything about a store to absolute address `1` segfaulting (which `mov %ebx, 0x1` would in at&t syntax mode).

---

**`mov  %ecx,string` loads from `string` into ecx**.  With `.intel_syntax noprefix`, you need `mov ecx, OFFSET string` to get the address as an immediate constant.  With intel_syntax "prefix" mode, you can probably `mov %ecx, $string` to get a `mov r32, imm32`

---

Put this in your `~/.gdbinit`:

```
set disassembly-flavor intel
layout reg
```

---

> Return code after sys_write is stored in %eax and is less 0

If you look it up, it should be `-EFAULT` for passing a bad address.

Comment: Thank you very much ! "OFFSET string" was the exact help.